# Docker registry v2 using a different S3 server

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-registry

In registry version 1, there were an option to redirect the registry to a custom S3 service, different than Amazons AWS:

```
-e AWS_HOST=other.s3.service.com
```

In registry version 2, I cannot find such an option / variable where I could direct the registry to different service. In the `confing.yml` the available paramaters does not contain any parameter like this under storage/s3.

Is there any way to define custom host for the S3 service in registry version 2?